# How to make a helper method to check existance status of an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-paranoid

I'm using Rails4, And also using [ActsAsParanoid](https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid) to handle deleted dependencies in my views.

**order.rb**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :ice_creams
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ice_creams
  validates :user, :shift, :discount, :total, :total_after_discount, :paid, :remaining, presence: true
  ...
end
```

**ice_cream.rb**

```
class IceCream < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :sauce, with_deleted: true
  belongs_to :order
  validates :size, :basis, :flavors, :ice_cream_price, :extras_price, :total_price, presence: true
  ...
end
```

**app/views/orders/show.html.erb**

```
...
<ul>
  ...
  <li>Total:<%= @order.total %><li>
</ul>

<% @order.ice_creams.each do |ice_cream| %>
  ...
  <ul class=leaders>
    <li>Ice Craem Id:<%= ice_cream.id %></li>
    <li>Sauce:<%= ice_cream.sauce.present? ? ice_cream.sauce.name : "Deleted Value!" %></li>
  ...
<% end %>
...
```

If i deleted a `sauce` `ActsAsParanoid` soft deletes it and save my views from breaking. And the `present?` method helped me with permanently deleted `sauces` but As you may see `sauces` are optional in any `ice_cream`, So If any `ice_cream` doesn't have a `sauce` that will also display `deleted value`.

So I had to come up with more logic to determine if any ice_cream has no sauce, or had a deleted sauce. So i wrote this helper method.

**application_helper.rb**

```
def chk(obj, atr)
  if send("#{obj}.#{atr}_id") && send("#{obj}.#{atr}.present?")
    send("#{obj}.#{atr}.name")
  elsif send("#{obj}.#{atr}_id.present?") and send("#{obj}.#{atr}.blank?")
    "Deleted Value!"
  elsif send("#{obj}.#{atr}_id.nil?")
    "N/A"
  end
end
```

and then used...

**app/views/orders/show.html.erb**

```
...
<%= chk(ice_cream, sauce %>
...
```

But It returnd `NoMethodError in Orders#show`

> undefined method `atr' for #< IceCream:0x007fcae3a6a1c0 >

My questions are...

- What's wrong with my code? and how to fix it?
- Overall, Is my approach considered a good practice to handle such situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I don't yet quite understand the whole situation so there might be a better solution but right now I can't propose it.

What is wrong with your current code I think is how you call `chk`.
It should be

```
...
<%= chk(ice_cream, 'sauce') %>
...
```

Notice that the second argument is a String instance (or it could a Symbol).

And I think your `chk` method should be something like this

```
def chk(obj, atr)
  attribute_id = obj.send("#{atr}_id")
  attribute = obj.send(atr)

  if attribute_id && attribute.present?
    attribute.name
  elsif attribute_id.present? and attribute.blank?
    "Deleted Value!"
  elsif attribute_id.nil?
    "N/A"
  end
end
```

I just refactored your method so it should be syntactically correct. But I haven't yet checked all those `if` logic.

**UPDATE**

Maybe it would be cleaner this way

```
def chk(obj, attr)
  attr_id  = obj.send("#{attr}_id")
  attr_obj = obj.send(attr)

  if attr_id.present?
    attr_obj.present? ? attr_obj.name : 'Deleted Value!'
  else
    'N/A'
  end
end
```